# How to refresh binding to property that doesn't support INotyfyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have some binding to third party object:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myString.Length}" />
```

How to refresh this binding programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have used google first :)

```
textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```